# Tironian notes (shorthand) in LaTeX

Tags: typography

I was wondering if it were possible to use Tironian notes in LaTeX, i.e. the shorthand introduced by Tiro (94 – 4 BC), as you can see in the following picture:

[image: tironian notes]

Is there a package to do this? Has anyone made this yet? Is there a specific font to insert these characters?

Comment: The link is a complete book. Can you show at least some of the symbols you need?

Comment: @egreg I added a picture.

Comment: I should note that Unicode only contains the “et” sign.

Comment: It doesn't appear that anyone has created a font for this. One could create such a font using FontForge and then use it with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: If desperate, one could save each of the symbols as an image, then declare shorthands in LaTeX for loading the corresponding image. E.g. you could write `\circa \de \exsuperat` and it would put the three images on the current line, as if you had used characters. This is a “poor man's” way of creating a font, though creating an actual font is not so hard that you cannot just do it the right way.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I just found on Wikipedia that _a number of other [than the et symbol] Tironian signs have been assigned to the Private Use Area of Unicode by the Medieval Unicode Font Initiative (MUFI), who also provide links to free typefaces that support their specifications_, but I don't know if this could help me or not.

Comment: If those fonts have the characters you need, then they will help. You will need to use Unicode, and compile with LuaLaTeX (or XeTeX) since prdlatex doesn't ordinarily reach into Unicode.

Comment: This won’t help you with typesetting Tironian notes, but you’ll want to know about http://www.martinellus.de/snt2/n/incipit.htm

Comment: @phaiderikos If you plan to write a scientific work about Tironian notes, it may be worth the time and effort to produce a digital version of the glyphs in your picture. If you only need some and it's more a nice-to-have kind of thing, maybe you can live with a number of carefully drawn xsaveboxes, one xsavebox for every glyph needed and use a picture of the glyph to this end. So tell us more about what you want to do.

Comment: @Keks Dose Actually, it’s only a nice-to-have thing. Surely it’s not worth the time to produce all the thousands of signs in a digital version: probably I’ll take the way in the middle, digitalizing only a small set of symbols I need (avoiding raster pictures).

Comment: Some of the characters have been added to Unicode on MUFI's request. MUFI is an open network for scholars, typographers etc. The [Recommendation](http://folk.uib.no/hnooh/mufi/specs/MUFI-Alphabetic-4-0.pdf) (search for "Spacing abbreviation and modifying characters" in the pdf) and thus the fonts only offer a subset of tironian notes that were considered to be of interest when _transcribing medieval sources_ by the researchers involved in the process. Expert involvement and suggestions for possible additions to future recommendations are welcome; please read more on mufi.info

Comment: Any additions to MUFI (or even much more to Unicode itself) are a lengthy process though. For _discussing_ the usage of the notæ you are probably best served with a solution as suggest by Keks Dose below anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need just some signes, not all of them, get them as graphic files, jgp or png will suit best. I got one glyph as png and made it »reusable« with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\xsavebox{termina}{\raisebox{-.6ex}{\includegraphics[width=1.3em]{termina}}}

\begin{document}

This Tironian sign \thetermina refers\\ to termination of words. It may be\\ used as
inline text. 

\end{document}
```

Which renders as this:

[image]

Comment: png doesn't suit best as it is one of the slowest image formats TeX can use.

Comment: Slow, in which regard, compilation speed?

Comment: @AlexG Long time ago I learned that png provides better quality for letters, while jpg is for photos. So I use png for such glyphs as tironian signs.

Comment: @KeksDose : Thanks. As long as vector graphics are not available, PNG is the format of choice. (My question was actually directed at Skillmon who raised speed considerations.)

Comment: @AlexG Then you need to address the question to him: »@Skillmon«.